# How remove empty nodes from adf menu tree

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I've created a tree component from a xml menu model and it was generated from an unbounded task flow.

I have this in my tree definition

```
<af:tree value="#{root_menu}" var="menuItem" 
          contentDelivery="immediate"
         immediate="true" fetchSize="25" id="pt_t1" clientComponent="true"
         initiallyExpanded="true"
         disclosedRowKeys="#{viewScope.treeMenuHelperBean.newDisclosedTreeKeys}"
                   inlineStyle="height:500.0px;"
                   binding="#{viewScope.treeMenuHelperBean.menuTree}">
            <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
            <af:group id="pt_g1">               
               <af:commandLink text="#{menuItem.label}" action="#{menuItem.doAction}"                                                               
                               id="pt_cl1" immediate="true" 
                               rendered="#{menuItem.rendered}"/>
            </af:group>
            </f:facet>
         </af:tree>
```

Some Command links are not rendered and it's ok but empty tree nodes are also generated
[image]

How can delete or hide or avoid generate empty nodes.

Answer (score 0):

These empty properly are empty labels, you can delete them from your root menu, or if you still want them you can control the rendered attribute to be something like this

```
rendered="#{menuItem.rendered and menuItem.label ne null}"
```